# Differentiating CEWP Headings

Tags: 2007, jquery, cewp

If I have a web part page with a number of Content Editor Web Parts and Custom Lists attached to them, how would I go about visually identifying them?  Changing the display txt isn't an option as this'll change links to them that have been embedded elsewhere.

I'm guessing something with JQuery is possible?  Ideally, I'd like to find a way to use the little green "new" icon that's used with new list items / documents.  Failing that, a simply a way to change the colour text would be handy.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could call the CEWP heading in jQuery and use the :last selector.  With that you can use any special css you want on that heading and as long as the 'new' ones are appearing after the existing elements it should update with that last one.

If you knew which ones you specifically wanted to use, you could also go with the .eq() approach.